# executable file not found in $PATH when trying to connect to a container in an AWS ECS EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ecs

I am having a hard to figuring out how to connect to my Docker container inside my EC2 instance via ssh.  Basically, I can get into the server okay and list my container using `docker ps`.

However, I can't get a shell inside of that container to run some shell scripts I need to get it running.

Locally, I just use ...

```
docker attach [cid] # or 'docker exec -it [cid] bash' to open new shell
```

... but there are obvious issues with running `docker attach` and with `docker exec -it [cid] bash` I am getting ...

```
rpc error: code = 2 desc = "oci runtime error: exec failed: exec: \"bash\": executable file not found in $PATH"
```

To provide some detail I believe I have set up ECS correctly.  From the applicable community AMI named amzn-ami-2016.03.e-amazon-ecs-optimized I have completed the following set up:

- An applicable ecsInstanceRole and ecsServiceRole
- A running EC2 instance.
- A Load Balancer pointing to that instance.
- A tagged repository in ECS.
- A ECS Task Definition pointing to ECS repository.
- A ECS Cluster with one instance slot allocated and has been successfully associated to the EC2 via(I believe) the start-up script. This cluster also has a service associated with the load balancer I mentioned as well as the associated task definition.

I don't believe this is where my issue lies(but maybe)

Perhaps it's my Dockerfile?

```
FROM    centos:centos6

RUN yum -y update; yum clean all; \
    yum groupinstall -y "Web Server" "MySQL Database" "PHP Support" "Development Tools"; \
    service httpd start; \
    chkconfig httpd on;

RUN yum install -y openssh openssh-clients git php-mysql php-gd php-imap php-ldap php-odbc php-pear php-xml php-xmlrpc php-mbstring php-mcrypt php-mssql php-snmp php-soap php-tidy curl curl-devel php-pecl-apc mysql;

# PHP
RUN sed -i '\%^<Directory "/var/www/html">%,\%^</Directory>% s/AllowOverride None/AllowOverride All/' /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf;

# MONGO
ADD docker/mongo/setup.sh /root/mongo.setup.sh

RUN chmod +x /root/mongo.setup.sh;

RUN yum install -y cyrus-sasl2 cyrus-sasl-devel php-devel; \
    echo "extension=mongo.so" >> /etc/php.ini;

# GIT CONFIG AND AUTH
ADD docker/ssh/ /root/.ssh/

RUN chmod 600 /root/.ssh/*; \
    touch /root/.ssh/known_hosts; \
    ssh-keyscan github.com >> /root/.ssh/known_hosts;

# EMAIL SES CONFIG AND AUTH
ADD docker/postfix/sasl_passwd /etc/postfix/sasl_passwd

ADD docker/postfix/main.appended.txt /etc/postfix/main.appended.txt

ADD docker/postfix/setup.sh /root/postfix.setup.sh

RUN chmod +x /root/postfix.setup.sh;

RUN yum install -y stunnel telnet telnet-server mailx postfix cyrus-sasl cyrus-sasl-plain cyrus-sasl-md5 cyrus-imapd postfix cyrus-sasl cyrus-sasl-plain cyrus-sasl-md5 cyrus-imapd openssl openssl-devel; \
    sed -i 's/-o smtp_fallback_relay=/#-o smtp_fallback_relay=/g' /etc/postfix/master.cf; \
    cat /etc/postfix/main.appended.txt >> /etc/postfix/main.cf; \
    chmod 600 /etc/postfix/main.appended.txt; \
    postmap hash:/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd;

# ADD YII LIBRARY
ADD docker/yii.tar.gz /var/www

# CLONE APPLICATION
RUN cd /var/www; \
    mkdir repo; \
    git clone git@github.com:myrepos.git html; \
    cd html; \
    git checkout production;

# NODE INSTALLATION
RUN yum install -y gcc gcc-c++ wget tar; \
    cd /root/; \
    wget http://nodejs.org/dist/v0.10.30/node-v0.10.30.tar.gz; \
    tar xzvf node-v*; \
    cd node-v*; \
    ./configure; \
    make; \
    make install;

# CREATE SOME DIRECTORIES FOR THE APPLICATION
RUN mkdir /var/www/.tmp; \
    mkdir /var/www/.tmp/data; \
    mkdir /var/www/coach_tests; \
    mkdir /var/www/html/protected/data/sessions; \
    mkdir /var/www/html/staging/protected/data/sessions; \
    mkdir /var/www/html/development/protected/data/sessions; \
    mkdir /var/www/html/protected/runtime; \
    mkdir /var/www/html/staging/protected/runtime; \
    mkdir /var/www/html/development/protected/runtime; \
    mkdir /var/www/html/assets; \
    mkdir /var/www/html/images/cache;

# GRUNT SETUP
ADD docker/www/Gruntfile.coffee /var/www/Gruntfile.coffee
ADD docker/www/package.json /var/www/package.json

RUN npm install -g grunt-cli; \
    cd /var/www; \
    npm install;

# S3 MOUNT CONFIG AND AUTH
ADD docker/s3/setup.sh /root/s3.setup.sh

RUN chmod +x /root/s3.setup.sh;

RUN yum install -y glib2-devel fuse-devel libevent-devel libxml2-devel; \
    cd /root/; \
    wget https://github.com/downloads/libevent/libevent/libevent-2.0.21-stable.tar.gz; \
    tar -xzf libevent-2.0.21-stable.tar.gz; \
    cd libevent-2.0.21-stable; \
    ./configure && make; \
    make install; \
    echo "/usr/local/lib/" > /etc/ld.so.conf.d/riofs.conf; \
    export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig; \
    ln -s /usr/local/lib/libevent-2.0.so.5 /usr/lib64/libevent-2.0.so.5; \
    cd ../; \
    git clone https://github.com/skoobe/riofs.git; \
    cd riofs; \
    ./autogen.sh; \
    ./configure; \
    make; \
    make install; \
    mkdir -p /var/www/html/images/user; \
    mkdir -p /var/www/html/images/store; \
    mkdir -p /var/www/html/images/sponsor; \
    mkdir -p /var/www/html/images/supporter; \
    mkdir -p /var/www/html/images/media;

# USEFUL TOOLS
ADD docker/startup.sh /root/startup.sh

RUN chmod +x /root/startup.sh;

RUN yum install -y nano;

# GRUNT INITIATE
RUN cd /var/www; \
    grunt init;
```

Comment: How exactly are you trying to connect to the containers? And what is it you're using Docker for? That's a lot of stuff in there.

Comment: We should separate ECS specific issues from those coming from your specific container settings. First off, are you able to successfully run this command in your ECS instance - `docker run -it centos:centos6 bash`? (Worked for me on our ECS instance)

Answer (score 2):

Oh man... sometimes when I am new to something I spend so much time looking for the small details that I gleam right over the more obvious issue.  In this particular case I ignored the "IMAGE" column in my `docker ps` listing assuming that it must have been my image without paying attention to anything else but the container ID.  The only running container was the `amazon/amazon-ecs-agent:latest` so no wonder I had issues getting a shell inside it.

It took Yaron's comment to remind me of this, as the `docker run` command was mentioned triggering an ah-ha moment.  I guess, I assumed it ran after the Task Definition thus the very reason I thought the only running container had to mine :P

After running `docker run -it -p 88:80 --privileged --cap-add MKNOD --cap-add SYS_ADMIN -d 1234546677788.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/my-ecs-repos /bin/bash` on the ECS EC2 instance, I was able visit the website and get a shell inside of the container :D

Answer (score 0):

Check which shell is installed in your image/container.

```
sudo docker exec -it [cid] echo $SHELL
```

If above command returns **/bin/bash**, then **docker exec -it [cid] bash** should work.

Otherwise you have to use the appropriate shell.

Comment: `/bin/bash` was returned, but the command is still not working.